# Resizing D3 force layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js, resize, force-layout

Is it possible to resize a force layout in d3.js? For example, I have a layout defined by

```
var force = d3.layout.force()
.nodes(documents.nodes)
.linkDistance(0)
.friction(.2)
.size([width, height]);

force.start();
```

and I wish to resize it later in the project. Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried resetting `.size()`?

Comment: I tried `force.size([newWidth, height]).start();` to no avail...

Comment: Note that increasing the size of the layout doesn't mean that the additional space will be used. What is your specific use case for this?

Comment: I have a few items on one page, and when focused on one of the other layouts, I'd like the force layout to shrink.

Comment: You'll also have to resize the container.

Comment: I tried `svg.attr("width", newWidth);
force.size([newWidth, height]).start();` (svg is the container), but only the container shrunk, and it just covers up the right half of the force layout...

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#wiki-size), the size doesn't actually affect where nodes will go. You'll have to enforce any hard constraints yourself.

Comment: Oh, interesting. Thanks very much, Lars.

Comment: I'll add that as an answer for reference.

Answer (score 4):

Shortly, on a resize event you should change the attributes of your *svg object* (it changes also the center of gravity) and resume force calculations:

```
window.onresize = function() {
  width = window.innerWidth, height = window.innerHeight;
  svg.attr('width', width).attr('height', height);
  force.size([width, height]).resume();
};
```

An example for the *d3 force* resize is [provided here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3355967).

Answer (score 3):

According to [the documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#wiki-size), the `.size()` parameter of the force layout affects only the center of gravity and initial distribution of nodes, not the space available. You will have to enforce any constraints on that yourself, e.g. in the `tick` function:

```
force.on("tick", function() {
    node.attr("cx", function(d) { return Math.min(maxX, Math.max(minX, d.x)); })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return Math.min(maxY, Math.max(minY, d.y)); });
}
```